# JPA EntityManager createQuery() error

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

This is failing:

```
public List<TypeActionCommerciale> requestTypeActionCommercialeSansNip() throws PersistenceException {
    Query query = createQuery("from TypeActionCommercialeImpl where type != :type1");
    query.setParameter("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP);
    return (List<TypeActionCommerciale>) query.list();
}
```

***exception:***

> Hibernate: select typeaction0_.id as id1_102_, typeaction0_.libelle as
>   libelle3_102_, typeaction0_.code as code4_102_, typeaction0_.type as
>   type5_102_ from apex.typeActionCommerciale typeaction0_ where
>   typeaction0_.type<>?
>
> ERROR 
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:129)
>
> - No value specified for parameter 1 org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet   at

i use setProperties but i have the same error:

```
public List<TypeActionCommerciale> requestTypeActionCommercialeSansNip() throws PersistenceException {
    Query query = createQuery("from TypeActionCommercialeImpl where type  <> :type1");
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP);
    query.setProperties(properties);
    return (List<TypeActionCommerciale>) query.list();
}
```

Comment: Hey guy, maybe you have to use setProperties method. Try !

Comment: The query is good.  The problem states that parameter 1 is missing.  Where is TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP?  It is like it is not in the classpath.  Can you try "from TypeActionCommercialeImpl where type != TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP" (and remove the setParameter line) to see what error you get

Comment: @IanMc error: `org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP], unexpected token [TypeActionCommercialeEnum] [from com.metier.impl.TypeActionCommercialeImpl where type   != TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP]
`

Comment: Better.  Now you can focus on the real problem.

Comment: How do you define type in the Entity class?

Comment: @IanMc `<property name="type" type="com.persistence.hibernate.userType.TypeActionCommercialeEnumUserType"/>`

Comment: There is a way to make this work with enums, but I see you are content to use strings.  Glad you have a solution.

Comment: @IanMc if you have a way to make to work with enums, i listen you

Comment: Oh dear, another one committing __bad practice__ of not starting their query with "SELECT alias".

Comment: @Neil Stockton can you explain me please

Comment: @NeilStockton Where you see the Select in my query ?

Comment: YOU HAVE NO SELECT IN YOUR QUERY!! You call createQuery("from TypeActionCommercialeImpl ..." ... there is NO SELECT. FFS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101668/discussion-between-mercer-and-neil-stockton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve my pb i have a class `public class EnumUserType<E extends Enum<E>> implements UserType` and i implement this method:

```
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
     String name = rs.getString(names[0]);  
        Object result = null;  
        if (!rs.wasNull()) {  
            result = Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);  
        }  
        return result;
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (null == value) {  
        st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);  
    } else {  
        st.setString(index, ((Enum<E>) value).name());  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here query.setParameter("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP);

The enum type is not defined in hibernate so you must store the name of enum and use it for the query (the easy way) then use:

```
query.setString("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP.name());
```

To use enum directly (the hard way) you must implement your CustomUserType . You can find here how https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom

The main advantages of use CustomUserType are:

1. you can store into DB an integer (that is more smaller) instead of a string that represents the enum.
2. Delegate the parsing to hibernate during storing and retrieving of object.
3. You can use the enum directly into the query (like you are trying to do)

Comment: What type is the field "type"?

Comment: `type character varying(255)`

Comment: The problem is that the keyword "type" is private keyword. Can you try to change the field name for a test please?

Comment: it's work under Hibernate 3 here i'm under Hibernate 5

Comment: it's very strange problem... try to use setString() and paste the stack trace

Comment: works with `setString()`  `query.setString("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP.name());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101626/discussion-between-mercer-and-andrea-catania).

Comment: can you explain me what's wrong with  `query.setParameter("type1", TypeActionCommercialeEnum.NIP);`

Comment: To use an enum type you must implement the UserType. Probably when you set the enum that not implemented UserType simply hibernate ignore the setted object...

Comment: I've added more information to my answer. I hope can help you. Bye!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<>` instead of `!=` like this:

```
  "from TypeActionCommercialeImpl where type <> :type1"
```

Comment: Use setProperties method Instead setParameter. And change != to <>

Comment: `The method getResultList() is undefined for the type Query`